# Update successful notice with pure css and a close button

Tags: css

i've seen websites that allow you to say update your profile and when the stuff is done, they'll stay in the same page or redirect you to another and with a fancy notice that says "Update successful. click here to close" with a lowered opacity black background and a box in the middle with the text within.

I've got most of the stuff, the lowred opacity black background, the middle box with the text and even the click here to close function.

But how i did the "Click here to close" function is by using a link.

Let's say after updating the profile, my script redirect me to index.php?update=successful then i use

```
$update = $_GET['update'];
if ($update == "successful") {
echo    '<div id="BlackScreen"><p id="MiddleBox">You\'ve successfully update your
status!<br><span class="close"><a class="menu" href="index.php">Click to close.
</a></span></div></div>';
}
```

so that the lowered opacity background div will be gone, but is there another way to do this? Any tips please?

Comment: Are you using any framework for javascript already?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I did spot that you never close your `<p>` tag and you're closing one too many `<div>` tags at the end.

Comment: No i didn't, purely css. Should i go for javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If javascript is an option (seems it might be from your comments), the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) example would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#BlackScreen a.menu").click(function() {
    $("#BlackScree").fadeOut();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with jquery, but i guess i'll give it a try, seem like a great idea, thanks!

Comment: I think i'll have to go back to javascript, jquery made it lag. Real bad.

Comment: @Crays - You just need to include jQuery itself, then the script above after, you include jquery by: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`  It shouldn't cause hardly any performance impact, do you have a lot of invalid HTML throwing it off?  You can check at http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Crays for javacript give that `<a>` and ID, then in script do `document.getElementById('theAnchorID').onclick = function() { document.getElementById('BlackScreen').style.display='none'; };`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the message when the user clicks a button or link, you'll need to use Javascript. In the simplest form, you could do this:

```
echo  '<div id="BlackScreen"><p id="MiddleBox">'
    . 'You\'ve successfully update your status!<br>'
    . '<span class="close">'
    . '<a '
    .   'onclick="document.getElementById(\'BlackScreen\').style.display=\'none\'; return false" '
    .   'class="menu" href="index.php">Click to close.'
    . '</a></span></div></div>';
```

It's not a great solution, but it's an example of how easy it *could* be.